# Image rendering in umbraco

Tags: asp.net, xslt, content-management-system, umbraco

I am working on a umbraco website http://wedclassis.com/. Initially everything was working fine but when i converted my site to have two languages, english and turkish, then my site is having problem while showimg images from media. Images appears some time and some times i get empty src even if print node for that image, it prints node number.  i am not understanding this unexpected behaviour of umbraco.

what i am using to render an image in xsl is:

```
<li>
 <xsl:variable name="slideImg" select="umbraco.library:GetXmlNodeById(@id)/sliderImages" />
    <xsl:if test="$slideImg &gt; 0">
        <img  alt="" style="display: block;">
        <xsl:attribute name="src">
        <xsl:value-of select="umbraco.library:GetMedia($slideImg, 0)/umbracoFile" />
        </xsl:attribute>
        </img>
 </xsl:if>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

So when it doesn't display the images does it not display the whole `<li>` element?

From the piece of code you've given there's nothing there about different logic for the different languages.  What if in your XSL template you remove this whole chunk of code and just take it back to basics.

```
<li>test</li>
```

I suspect that the language choice is messing something else up somewhere else in the page.  Just try simplifying the page one step at a time by removing the Macros.

Answer (score 0):

if you are working on c# code then use following

Header.ascx

```
 <asp:Image ID="imgMobileLogo" runat="server" CssClass="mobile_header" AlternateText="" />
```

Code Behind (Header.ascx.cs)

Page Load

```
 Node headerNode = Common.GetHeaderFolder();
```

image code

```
 if (headerNode.GetProperty(FieldName.HEROMOBILEBACKGROUNDIMAGE) != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(headerNode.GetProperty(FieldName.HEROMOBILEBACKGROUNDIMAGE).Value)) {
                    string url = Common.GetMediaImageUrl(headerNode, FieldName.HEROMOBILEBACKGROUNDIMAGE);
                    imgMobileLogo.ImageUrl = url;
                }
```

Here HEROMOBILEBACKGROUNDIMAGE = image field name;
&
you have to define function GetHeaderFolder() in common.cs file
and ALIAs of your fields.